# How to check dependency in excel columns and display error in excel-vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of columns in my excel. For the sake of simplicity, lets consider it Potato, Tomato, Currency1, Amount1, Currency2, Amount2 ... Currency10, Amount10

If Currency1 or Amount1is empty; then it should fill both the cells in red color
else; it should ignore those cells.

I have tried the following thing. However, its not working out for my case and I have to include a lot of iterations. Please suggest a better way if possible.

My code is as follows:

```
' Function to get last column
cols = LastColumnInOneRow()
' Function to get last row
Rows = fnLastRowOfAColumn(cols)

For num_cols = 1 To cols
    For num_rows = 2 To Rows
        cell_value = Cells(num_rows, num_cols)
        Set selected_attr = Cells(1, num_cols)
        Select Case selected_attr
            Case Is = "Currency1"
                If Cells(num_rows + 1, num_cols) <> "" Then
                    Cells(num_rows, num_cols).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                Else
                    Cells(num_rows, num_cols).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If

            Case Is = "Amount1"
                If Cells(num_rows - 1, num_cols) <> "" Then
                    Cells(num_rows, num_cols).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                Else
                    Cells(num_rows, num_cols).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If

            ' Till end of sheet ...
        End Select
    Next num_rows '+ 1
Next num_cols '+ 1
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use VBA? Conditional formatting can do this and it will auto-update.

Comment: @Mark_Anderson I have many regular expressions hence I have to do it in VBA. I tried it in the first place however it didnt workout that well for me

Comment: If the problem is literally "make cells red if A1 is blank" as you describe above  then conditional formatting is the easiest way to go.  More complex conditions like "colour entire row based on Col A" are also very possible is you can write an excel formula to describe the condition.  Definitely what I'd use if I were in your position.  Just takes 30 mins to learn their quirks!

Comment: Are you looking for empty in Cells "A1" and "A2" only ? or every couple of cells ? like also "B1" and "B2", etc...?

Comment: Looking at your code `Case Is = "A1"` isn't testing against the value of Cell A1 -- it tests against the string "A1".   You want `Range("A1").Value` I assume?

Comment: @ShaiRado I am looking for all the cells all the way from A1, A2 till Z1, Z2

Comment: @Mark_Anderson A1, A2 are just for the sake of simplicity. They got nothing to do with cells notations

Comment: You need to rewrite the question and toy code. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve or how you are trying to do it.

Comment: The best suggestion I have, assuming "A1" is some complex test you carry out per row, is to dump the value of that test into its own cell/row/column (I don't know what your structure is) and then use that value to run the test rather than hide all this processing in VBA.  Keep it simple and all that...

Comment: @Mark_Anderson Ive updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry I cannot comment but I can give you the following tip:

You can eventually set up conditional formatting as a vba code, here is an example to set your range to red if not empty as a conditional formatting:

```
Range("A2", Cells(Rows, Cols)).FormatConditions.Delete 'this would eventually delete previous formating
With Range("A2", Cells(Rows, Cols)).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlNotEqual, "=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34))
    .Interior.ColorIndex  = 3
End With
```

Edit: here is an example to set your range to green if your cell is equal to 'Currency1' and the cell bellow is empty as a conditional formatting:

```
With Range("A2", Cells(Rows, Cols)).FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, , "= AND(A3<>" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "; A2=" & Chr(34) & "Currency1" & Chr(34) & ")")
    .Interior.ColorIndex  = 4
End With
```

Comment: The Amounts and currencies can be in any cell. It specifically need not be in A2 or A3 (example)

Comment: I don't understand your comment *'It specifically need not be'* could you clarify? my example cover a whole range from `A2` to `Cells(Rows, Cols)`

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted your answer. It is partially correct and I have a dependency on next cell as well if you go read through my question.

Comment: Conditional formatting also can depend of the next cell, I will add an example to the answer

Comment: How do you suggest can I do this for a long spreadsheet having 26 columns to be validated in the same manner ?

Comment: What about using `range("A:Z")` or `Columns(1).Resize(, 26)` as Range? this cover 26 columns entirely. I do not add this in the answer because I cannot yet see the link with the original question.

Comment: I might have more than that 26 columns in future and my vba program needs to be flexible

Comment: sure the best for custom number of column between a and b is `Columns(a).Resize(, b)` but does it answer your question?

Comment: What if I have large rows.. how will it affect the output or performance ?

Comment: does the size of the row impact vba performance in excel? I don't know and most likely no. but again it is a different question... and you did not mention how much I reply to the previous question.

Comment: Okay. No problem @Jonathan the code posted by me works as intended as well. +1 for your answer

Comment: Sure your are free to choose your answer, good luck for the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

I solved my that scenario using the following in Amount1, Amount2 .. Amount10:

```
                If IsEmpty(Cells(num_rows, num_cols + 1)) = True And IsEmpty(Cells(num_rows, num_cols)) = True Then

                    If .Test(cell_value) = False Then
                        Cells(num_rows, num_cols).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    Else
                        Cells(num_rows, num_cols).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                    End If
                    Set RegEx = Nothing
                    End With
                ElseIf (IsEmpty(Cells(num_rows, num_cols + 1)) = False And IsEmpty(Cells(num_rows, num_cols)) = True) Then
                    Cells(num_rows, num_cols).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    Cells(num_rows, num_cols + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                ElseIf (IsEmpty(Cells(num_rows, num_cols + 1)) = True And IsEmpty(Cells(num_rows, num_cols)) = False) Then
                    Cells(num_rows, num_cols + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    Cells(num_rows, num_cols).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                Else
                    Cells(num_rows, num_cols).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                    Cells(num_rows, num_cols + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                End If
```